# Installing Oracle 10g server where there is already a client?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

i have a Windows Server on which there is already a Oracle 10g client with tnsnames.ora and access to many databases.

I would like to install a Oracle 10g server on it..

Will it break the current Client configuration ?  will i have several tnsnames.ora ?
how will i have to manage databases created on this server ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this.

We chose:

```
/oracle/home/product/10.2.0/db_1[server code & install]
/oracle/home/product/10.2.0/client_1[client software & install]
```

Unless the server needs db links to everything, we limit the db_1 tree's tnanames.ora file to whatever db's we will have running on that box only.

The client_1 tree needs to know about everything out there.  We have a single tnsnames.ora that is installed on every client.  It has all of the db's.

I have no idea what managmement tasks you will need.  Setting up and sizing schema objects (tables) comes to mind.